# My program is deleting a character from a string, how to avoid that?

Tags: c++, string

I have this program that is supposed to find a string of 3 chars, say "abc" into a longer string say "aabccbd" and then replace the coincidence with another char (say 'd') into the original string. So. Given those strings the results would be:

1. `aabcabcd`
2. `adabcd <<-- another iteration`
3. `addd <<-- Final result`

And I've written a few code lines that *I believe* solve the problem of replacing the given sequence (Still haven't programmed the displacing of chars). But the thing is that when I replace the sequence with the given char, the char that is before the sequence gets deleted. 
Example:

1. `aabcabcd`
2. `dabcd <<-- Incorrect`

What could possibly be wrong? Check my code please. The sequence is read from a .txt file with the following format:

`a b c d` <- Sequence and swapping character. (Sequence is always 3 chars long)
`abcdefakxoqp333` <- Complete string where I'm supposed to search for the sequence.

```
Code:
#include<stdio.h>
#include<iostream>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<string.h>
using namespace std;
char* gen = new char[3];
char simp;
char dna[10001];

int main() {
    int len;
    //Reading file and assigning values.
    FILE *input = fopen("input.txt","rt");
    fscanf(input,"%c %c %c %c",&gen[0],&gen[1],&gen[2],&simp);
    fscanf(input,"%s",&dna);
    fclose(input);
    len = strlen(dna);
    //In this part dna has the 2nd line of input.txt
    for(int i=0;i<len;i++){
        cout << dna[i];
    }
    cout << endl;
    //Searching for coincidences.

    int dnaLen = len; //dna Lenght, this one will change over time.
    bool found=false;
    int index=0; //Index will be reseted as well when we make a change!!
    while(index<dnaLen-2) {
            cout << "Entering WHILE with index=" << index << "\n";
            cout << "Examining: " << dna[index] << dna[index+1] << dna[index+2] << endl;
        if(dna[index]=gen[0] && dna[index+1]==gen[1] && dna[index+2]==gen[2]){
            //Replace dna[index] for simp AND displace the dna array
            dna[index]=simp;
            for(int i=0;i<dnaLen;i++){
                cout << dna[i];
            }
            cout << endl;
            index =0;
            dnaLen=dnaLen-2;
        }
        index++;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

I know I can try with regex, the thing is I'm kind of restricted on the use of C++11. 
I also know I can use [string::replace](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/replace/) but what's wrong with this code? Thank you!

Comment: You can replace `char* gen = new char[3];` with `char * gen[3];`, since the array size is constant.

Comment: This -> `dna[index]=gen[0]` is a silent error.

Comment: You could try [**addressing your compiler warnings**](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/6a5af3d7a690b5f3).

Comment: *"what's wrong with this code?"* - Basically, its biggest problem is the fact that you have written a C program with some C++ decoration. Don't use `fscanf` and friends, don't use raw arrays. Make use of that `#include <iostream>` and use what's in there, and use `std::string` and/or `std::vector`.

Comment: @WhozCraig No compile warnings!

Comment: @DavidMerinos did you see [**the link I provided**](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/6a5af3d7a690b5f3)? The warnings specifically call out the problem the accepted answer describes.

Comment: @WHOZCRAIG Oh sorry, didn't see the link. Thank you for that too. Code::Blocks doesnt throw any warnings. Any recommendations on a better compiler are accepted.

Comment: @DavidMerinos Code::Blocks isn't a compiler; its an IDE. The back-end compiler is likely gcc or clang. Head to the C++ compiler configuration properties in Code::Blocks (I have no idea how to reach them, but I know they're there somewhere) and check all warnings, extra warnings, warnings-as-errors, etc. Its worth it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is not a comparison but assignment, replace `=` with `==`

```
if(dna[index]=gen[0]...
```

Comment: +1 Its worse than just an assignment operation. The problem is compounded as an assignment of an unintended boolean eval for the remainder of the expression.

Comment: I can't believe I missed that. It's working now. I'm going to attack the other problem of displacing the string. Thank you!